# my leopard gecko come to shedding her skin is white .pass a 15 munites she have a normal skin . I dont see she shedsing before

Tags: leopard-geckos, molting

my leopard gecko come to shedding her skin is white .pass a 15 munites she have a normal skin . I dont see she shedsing before.
her body is normal. Dont have any skin from shedding